# Capturing output from interactive, embedded terminal

Tags: neovim

I'm working on a Neovim plugin that's basically rich integration for an external CLI program. Users of this plugin would typically already be regular manual CLI users of this program. When my plugin needs to shell out to the CLI, I'd like to have the option to have that process run inside an interactive shell session in the embedded terminal. This puts the invocations into shell history, so they can easily be modified manually or looked up later.

I know I can send input to the terminal via its PTY [channel](https://neovim.io/doc/user/nvim_terminal_emulator.html#terminal-status) but is there any way to access its stdout and exit codes, e.g. by attaching callbacks? Especially since the process would be running inside the interactive shell, not directly as the command passed to `:terminal`, I don't see an easy way to do it. Can't just read the buffer, and TermClose autocommands won't work.

I.e. is there a way I can implement something like [plenary.job](https://github.com/nvim-lua/plenary.nvim#plenaryjob) but have that job execute inside a currently running shell in embedded terminal?